# visualizing correlations on specific class in a target

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, correlation, data-science, data-analysis

I have a Dataset that consists of four classes, meaning the target variable has 4 different classes (like 0,1,2,3) 
as we know we can obtain most correlated features to our target by pandas using this snippet.

```
# Find correlations with the target and sort
correlations = train.corr()['Target'].sort_values()
# Display correlations
print('Most Positive Correlations:\n', correlations.tail(15))
print('\nMost Negative Correlations:\n', correlations.head(15))
```

but my question is, i need to obtain most correlated features to specific target class. for example i want to get which features have high effect(correlated) on target class 3. I have tried this,

```
correlations = train.corr()[(train['Target'] == 3)].sort_values()
```

but it gives this error

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the 
boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

[my expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHjoZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us anything to work with but I'm assuming your problem is calling `.corr()` before masking. You need to call:

```
correlations = train[(train['Target'] == 3)].corr().sort_values()
```

Edit:

A more elegant solution is probably `groupby`. Try something along the lines of:

```
train.groupby('Target').apply(lambda grp: grp.corr())
```

Comment: Brian, thanks for your reply, the only think left that i can provide you is the dataset which is not possible, but assume you have a train dataset that the target variable has four different labels, and you need to see the correlation of features on specific label (class). Also your code gave me this error, even-though i dont think it will what i needed. TypeError: sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'

Comment: @JamaHusseinMohamud, This error is due to sort_values requiring a column to sort on when you call the method on a DataFrame. I don't know what your columns are, but if you supply `sort_values` with a column name that should fix the error. Just remove sort_values all-together if you want to just see the correlations.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i have tried both options, and it gives NAN values under the target. in other words, both of these options will give you the correlation between features but will not give you the correlation between features and specific label in target feature.

Comment: @JamaHusseinMohamud, sorry it's not working out but it's hard for me to debug what's going on without any data to give me an idea